# Scala How to Intersect Maps of types Map[String, Double] inside a List of: List[Map[String, Double]]

Tags: list, scala, maps, intersect

So I have a list of maps: List[Map[String, Double]].
An example of it would be:

```
List(Map("A" -> 1.1, "B" -> 2.5, "E" -> 3.5, "C" -> 1.6, "D" -> 0.9), 
        Map("A" -> 0.8, "C" -> 2.1, "D" -> 2.8), 
        Map("C" -> 2.2, "D" -> 2.9, "A" -> 3.4), 
        Map("B" -> 0.4, "D" -> 1.8, "E" -> 0.234, "A" -> 3.7))
```

What I want to do is to get the intersect of all of the maps together so then it looks like:

```
   For example, for A: (1.1 + 0.8 + 3.4 + 3.7)/4 = 2.25
                for D: (0.9 + 2.8 + 2.9 + 1.8)/4 = 2.1

   List(Map("A" -> 2.25,"D" -> 2.1))
```

Is there a way to get the intersected list of map above using built in functions only? The values are the average of all of the keys in the four maps combined.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by intersect? Where did you get the `2.25` and `2.1` from? If you have a function `f` to intersect two Maps already, you can do `list.reduce(f)` or `list.foldLeft(Map())(f)`

Comment: I get that you want to get only the repeated keys, but what is the logic for the values? The mean? - Also, are you open to external libraries? There is no std function that x a do this out of the box, but **cata** does provide something closer.

Comment: No external libraries if possible. Would it be possible to do it using the intersect() function with other functions added on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try first using `reduce` to keep only duplicate keys and add up all the values, and then use `mapValues` to get the mean:

```
val maps = List(...)

val intersected = maps
  .reduce { (m1, m2) =>
    m1.keySet.intersect(m2.keySet).map(key => (key, m1(key) + m2(key))).toMap
  }
  .view
  .mapValues(_ / maps.size)
  .toMap
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7NkOI907TzeWUpy1kaQIow)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552478/intersection-and-merge-join-two-maps-in-scala) is similar.

Answer (score 3):

Have to be careful that the input isn't empty.

```
val lm : List[Map[String,Double]] =
  List(Map("A" -> 1.1, "B" -> 2.5, "E" -> 3.5, "C" -> 1.6, "D" -> 0.9)
      ,Map("A" -> 0.8, "C" -> 2.1, "D" -> 2.8)
      ,Map("C" -> 2.2, "D" -> 2.9, "A" -> 3.4)
      ,Map("B" -> 0.4, "D" -> 1.8, "E" -> 0.234, "A" -> 3.7))

val len = lm.length
val res = if (len > 0)
            lm.map(_.keySet)
              .reduce(_ intersect _)
              .map(k => (k, lm.map(_(k)).sum/len))
              .toMap
          else Map.empty[String,Double]
//res: Map[String,Double] = Map(A -> 2.25, D -> 2.1)
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the case where the input is empty. +1

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have:

```
val list = List(Map("A" -> 1.1, "B" -> 2.5, "E" -> 3.5, "C" -> 1.6, "D" -> 0.9),
  Map("A" -> 0.8, "C" -> 2.1, "D" -> 2.8),
  Map("C" -> 2.2, "D" -> 2.9, "A" -> 3.4),
  Map("B" -> 0.4, "D" -> 1.8, "E" -> 0.234, "A" -> 3.7))
```

Another option you have is (only Scala 2.13):

```
val stringToDoubles =
  list.flatten
    .groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
    .filter(_._2.size == list.size)
    .map(keyAndValues => (keyAndValues._1, keyAndValues._2.sum / list.size))
```

Code run can be found at [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YZ5eb2f9RHaTCSdxQEskTw).

In Scala 2.12 and below it will be:

```
val stringToDoubles =
  list.flatten
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .filter(_._2.size == list.size)
    .map(keyAndValues => (keyAndValues._1, keyAndValues._2.map(_._2).sum / list.size))
```

Code run can be found at [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7zNiYO93THyhUCcKTT4shQ).

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using external libraries, this becomes very simple with **cats**:

```
import cats.data.NonEmptyList
import cats.syntax.all._

val data = NonEmptyList.of(
  Map("A" -> 1.1, "B" -> 2.5, "E" -> 3.5, "C" -> 1.6, "D" -> 0.9),
  Map("A" -> 0.8, "C" -> 2.1, "D" -> 2.8),
  Map("C" -> 2.2, "D" -> 2.9, "A" -> 3.4),
  Map("B" -> 0.4, "D" -> 1.8, "E" -> 0.234, "A" -> 3.7)
)

val result =
  data
    .nonEmptySequence
    .fmap { group =>
      val (sum, count) = group.foldMap(_ -> 1)
      sum / count
    }
// result: Map[String, Double] = HashMap(A -> 2.25, D -> 2.1)
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/yhi0ZNd1SKimG7W09eT9JQ/7)*.